# Do Azure Functions deployment slots implement x-ms-routing-name?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-function-app, azure-deployment-slots

I've been testing deployment slots for web apps. By attaching x-ms-routing-name to the query parameters you can redirect a call to a deployment slot (although you first need to manually change the traffic % for it to work).

Now I'm setting up deployment slots for Azure Functions to do the same thing.
However it seems the x-ms-routing-name is not acknowledged?
I also cannot change the traffic % for the deployment slots as they're disabled in the app service plan.

Can anyone confirm that x-ms-routing-name is not implemented/acknowledged for Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone confirm that x-ms-routing-name is not implemented/acknowledged for Functions?

I confirm with Microsoft support engineer and it seems that [function deployment slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots) do not support to route traffic with `x-ms-routing-name`.

If you still want to achieve this functionality, you could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions) to azure function to promote this to be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation. I noticed on the Functions Live webcast there will be an overhaul of the Portal experience, making it more like App Service. Does that also mean the way deployment slots are handled will be aligned?

Comment: This one has to ask the product group and I do not confirm it. You could give your feedback and wait for good news.